# Como lleno un arreglo bidimensional con 5 palabras diferentes dejando espacios y sin repetirse?

Tags: java, poo, fórmulas-de-matriz

**debo llenar esto de manera aletoria**
**Es como hacer la matriz 15 x 15 y luego colocar esas 5 palabras sin repetirlas**

public class arreglo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random Ram = new Random();
    int palabras; //variable que ceo debo usar
    int Filas, Columnas; //variables filas
    char matriz[][];

    matriz = new char[15][15];// Creacion matriz
    
    String alphabet = ("p1"+"p2"+"p3"+"p4"+p5");//lista de palabras
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {//2 ciclos para recorrer matriz
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) { 
            matriz[i][j] = (char) (alphabet.charAt(Ram.nextInt(alphabet.length())));//llena la matriz con las palabras de manera aleatoria
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder separar las palabras correctamente tienes que usar un separador entre ellas, es decir si tienes un solo string con una palabra detras de otra tienes que poner un caracter entre cada palabra que te sirva de separador.

Además, habría que cambiar el tipo de la matriz, ya que dices que cada elemento es una palabra este no puede ser un tipo "char" sino "String".

Una solucion utlizando ";" como separador sería:

```
    Random Ram = new Random();
    int palabras; //variable que ceo debo usar
    int Filas, Columnas; //variables filas
    String matriz[][];

    matriz = new String[15][15];// Creacion matriz
    
    String alphabet = ("p1;"+"p2;"+"p3;"+"p4;"+"p5;");//lista de palabras // Una cadena con este aspecto: "p1;p2;p3;p4;p5"
    
    List<String> palabrasSeparadas = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split(";"))); // pasamos el array de palabras a una lista para que sea mas sencillo

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length && !palabrasSeparadas.isEmpty(); i++) { //2 ciclos para recorrer matriz //Comprobar si no quedan palabras por añadir para evitar Excepcion 
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length && !palabrasSeparadas.isEmpty(); j++) { 
            int r = Ram.nextInt(palabrasSeparadas.size());
            matriz[i][j] = palabrasSeparadas.get(r); //llena la matriz con las palabras de manera aleatoria
            palabrasSeparadas.remove(r);    // Se elimina de la lista para que no se repita      
        }
    }
```

Comment: Claro, te entiendo perfectamente, los valores son aleatorios pero solo se ponen en la primera linea, creo me toca implementar metodos para que se puedan ubicar las palabras en cualquier lugar de la matriz debo ver como hago eso y ya por fin solucionaria todo. tu respuesta me ayudo mucho. GRACIAS.

Comment: De nada! me alegra poderte ayudar. Quizas puedes generar un par de listas, una para los indices de las filas y otra para las columnas, mezclarlas con el metodo "Collections.shuffle()" y vas cogiendo los indices para la matriz de ahi. :D Edito: solo haria falta una lista con todos los pares de indices posibles. (ejemplo: [(1,3), (2,5),(2,8),...])